# I use the words "That is" too much. What are some good replacement for these two words?

Tags: synonyms

I use the words "That is" too much. What are some good replacements for these two words?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please [edit] your question to give examples of how you currently use "that is"?

Comment: Is this in conversation or in a written document?  If written, what is the nature of the document (**i.e.** is it technical)?

Comment: Right now it's super-unclear what sorts of uses of this particular collocation are bothering you, so please edit your question to include several examples of the types of use you're making of these two words for which you’re seeking potential suitable alternatives. Doing so will automatically nominate your question for reöpening. E.g.: *“Hi, I’m looking for a book **that is** out of print.“ “My goodness but **that is** far too dear for my pocketbook!” “A little bit of **that is** all I need.“ “All West Coast states (**that is,** CA, OR, WA, and AK, but not of course BC) are united in this.”*

Answer (score 2):

Replacing a repetitive phrase with another doesn’t solve the underlying problem. Instead of looking for alternative words, rewrite the paragraph or sentence.

Here’s an illustrative example.

First, a somewhat stilted block with a couple of “that is” instances:

- He came to the hotel on his own. That is, he provided his own transport and just showed up. That is, we aren’t responsible for him being here.

Now change one of the instances to something else:

- He came to the hotel on his own. That is, he provided his own transport and just showed up. In other words, we aren’t responsible for him being here.

The cadence is still pretty much the same despite removing the repetition through substitution.

Now consider a reworded block:

- We aren’t responsible for him being here. He found his way to the hotel on his own initiative.

The staccato feel of the original has morphed into something more fluid.

Noticeable, unwanted, repetitions should be treated as an invitation to redraft because the problem lies with the structure of the writing, not the words *per se*.